# Cleaning Origin and Destination data with duplicates but different factor level

Tags: r, duplicates, data.table, gis, data-cleaning

I have some GIS data with origins and destinations (OD) and an information about the time of the day of the OD. I intending to make a map of this, and to color the ODs by the time of day information.

One thing is that some ODs are in the data set with both day and night and maybe with a different order. I would like to mark those differntly, e.g. "Day/Night"

Is there an easy way to do this? MY MWE is just one OD but I would need to identify it among several others. I can manage to find the duplicates regardless of the order, but I dont know how to find out wether or not there are both time cases there and how to replace them with "Day/Night"

```
library(data.table)
Origin<-c("London", "Paris", "Lisbon", "Madrid", "Berlin", "London")
Destination<-c("Paris", "London", "Berlin","Lisbon", "Lisbon", "Paris")
Time=factor(c("Day", "Night", "Day", "Day/Night","Day", "Day/Night"))
dt<-data.table(Origin=Origin, Destination=Destination, Time=Time)
#duplicates regardless of order
dat.sort = t(apply(dt[,.(Origin,Destination)], 1, sort))
dt[duplicated(dat.sort) | duplicated(dat.sort, fromLast=TRUE),]
```

Comment: So are you trying to find if there is a case where there would be two records at day time for same 2 countries?

Comment: I am trying to find records for the same origin destination that run both at day and night and I would like to recode them "Night/Day"

Answer (score 1):

You can do that using dplyr package as follows;

Feel free to change the conditions to what fits your need.

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

# Creating data
dt <- 
  data.table(
    Origin = c("London", "Paris", "Italy", "Spain", "Portugal", "Poland"),
    Destination = c("Paris", "London", "Norway", "Portugal", "Spain", "Spain"),
    Time = c("Day", "Night", "Day", NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_)
  )

dt

# Origin Destination  Time
# London   Paris      Day
# Paris    London     Night
# Italy    Norway     Day
# Spain    Portugal   <NA>
# Portugal Spain      <NA>
# Poland   Spain      <NA>

dt %>%
  # pmin and pmax are used to sort the 2 columns
  # in order to group by them regardless to their order
  group_by(Origin2 = pmin(Origin, Destination), 
           Destination2 = pmax(Origin, Destination)) %>%
  mutate(count = n(), # To check if Origin/destination are repeated or not
         row = row_number(), # Place holder to know if it was first to repeat or second
         # If not repeated then make Time = Day
         # If repeated and first occurance then Time = Day
         # If repeated and second occurance then Time = Night
         Time = case_when(count == 1 ~ "Day",
                          count == 2 & row == 1 ~ "Day",
                          count == 2 & row == 2 ~ "Night")) %>%
  ungroup() %>%
  select(Origin, Destination, Time)

# Origin   Destination Time 
# <chr>    <chr>       <chr>
#   1 London   Paris       Day  
# 2 Paris    London      Night
# 3 Italy    Norway      Day  
# 4 Spain    Portugal    Day  
# 5 Portugal Spain       Night
# 6 Poland   Spain       Day
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the dplyr solution by @Nareman Darwisch that gave me the inspiration for my solution with `data.table`

I am creating a new variable as a unique ID for each Origin Destination

```
dat.sort = t(apply(dt[,.(Origin,Destination)], 1, sort))
dt.temp<-data.table(dat.sort)
dt.temp[,unique.name:=paste(V1,V2)]
dt$unique.name<-factor(dt.temp$unique.name)
```

Then I can either calculate the length of the unique occurences of the factor by group or if they match more than once with any of the 3 levels. Based on this I can recode the labels with the "Day/Night" level whenever the length is > 1 or the other condition is TRUE

```
dt[,No.levels:=length(unique(c(Time))), by=unique.name]
dt[,No.levels.logi:=sum(c(Time) %in% c(1:3))>1 , by=unique.name]
```

The thing I would like to understand how I could use a logical condition in the spirit of looking at the levels by group and compares those with the cases I want.

```
dt[,No.levels.logi:=sum(levels(Time) %in% c("Day", "Night"))>1 , by=unique.name]
```

But I guess the levels command always gives me all three levels.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, the OP wants to

- identify city pairs regardless of the order of origin and destination, e.g. London-Paris belongs to the same city pair as Paris-London
- collapse separate rows if a city pair is operated `Day` *and* `Night` *or* `Day/Night`
- or update the original dataset

This is what I would do:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(Origin, Destination, Time)
# add city pair as unique grouping variable
dt[, Pair := paste(pmin(Origin, Destination), pmax(Origin, Destination), sep = "-")][]
# identify city pairs which are operated day and night
pairs_DN <- dt[, all(c("Day", "Night") %in% Time) | "Day/Night" %in% Time, by = Pair][(V1), .(Pair)]
# update original dataset by an update join
dt[pairs_DN, on = "Pair", Time := "Day/Night"][]
```

> ```
>    Origin Destination      Time          Pair
> 1: London       Paris Day/Night  London-Paris
> 2:  Paris      London Day/Night  London-Paris
> 3: Lisbon      Berlin       Day Berlin-Lisbon
> 4: Madrid      Lisbon Day/Night Lisbon-Madrid
> 5: Berlin      Lisbon       Day Berlin-Lisbon
> 6: London       Paris Day/Night  London-Paris
> ```

The key point is to identify the city pairs which fullfil the second requirement:

```
dt[, all(c("Day", "Night") %in% Time) | "Day/Night" %in% Time, by = Pair]
```

> ```
>             Pair    V1
> 1:  London-Paris  TRUE
> 2: Berlin-Lisbon FALSE
> 3: Lisbon-Madrid  TRUE
> ```

So, there is no need to deal with factor levels. BTW, factor levels are an attribute of the whole column and do not change when subsetting or grouping. What does change is which of the levels are used in a subset or group.

`pairs_DN` contains the unique key of those city pairs

> ```
>             Pair
> 1:  London-Paris
> 2: Lisbon-Madrid
> ```